# Arcgis Server 10.1: Workflow/Setup for Secure Content?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, security

We have a server which has ports 80 and 6080 open to the outside world--and probably port 443 as well. But port 6643--the default secure port for ArcGIS Server is not open to the outside. The server also has a functioning Web Adapter for port 80 based calls to Services. This is a Windows 2008 Server.

My supervisor wanted me to install an SSL certificate on urgent basis; so I have enabled both HTTPS/HTTP on the server and also created and sent a .csr file to our IT staff so they get as a CA issued SSL certficate. But for now at least we can, inside the network, get to  even with see the security warning and browser exception option.

But, according to this: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/61639 we should not install the CA issued SSL on our server? If not then how to protect content? Let's say if there are applications accessing Services and logins to port 6080 or 80 then they remain not secure. So we will need to have a genuine SSL certificate in the picture. But how?

This is my first time dealing with ArcGIS Server's SSL layer and so my apologies if I am way off. Just trying to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what we are ending up doing:

1) Installed an SSL Certificate on our ArcGIS 10.x server, per ESRI online instructions. We have enabled both https/http access.

2) We have our network department opened port 6443 to the outside; we would have used IIS's port 443 but the Certificate issued to us was not .pfx format.

3) We will be serving secure content through ... end points.

HTH

Comment: You can accept your own answer with the checkbox